# Как работает инструмент Responsive в браузере?

Tags: css, responsive

У меня есть body с шириной 1910px. Но когда я открываю инструменты разработчика и ставлю там ширину 1910px, я вижу только кусок моей верстки. Почему? Почему пиксели которые я указываю в css не совпадают с пикселями в инструменте responsive?
css:

```
body {
background: green url(../../img/bgall-min.png) no-repeat;
width: 1910px;
/* background-size: 100vw; */
letter-spacing: 0.085em;
font-family: 'Roboto';
font-weight: normal;
}
```

Скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересно было бы узнать в каком смысле не совпадают?

Comment: наверно viewport забыли указать

Comment: @Air, Я так понимаю, что если я указал в Responsive ширину 1910px, то это окно эмулирует экран с шириной 1910px, и поэтому моя картинка (с шириной 1910px) будет занимать ровно 100% экрана.

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, если я укажу background-size: 100vw, то изображение будет занимать 100% ширины окна браузера, но что делать с пикселями?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то нет, эмулирует...  `1910px` и в африке `1910px`

Comment: я же сказал о viewport

Comment: я щас проверил ..поставил у body width:1900px margin:auto; и meta:viewport и всё отображается нормально ...весь фон попал в экран

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, может, скинете ваш код? Я тогда, наверное, пойму что у меня не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так проверьте...

Только я проверял здесь уже на большем разрешении

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      width: 2200px;
      min-height: 100vh;
      margin: auto;
      background: url(https://user32265.clients-cdnnow.ru/originalStorage/41/e6/9f/19/41e69f19.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает... Надо подучить viewport, значит